# Use the Euler–Maclaurin formula to find $P_{k+1}$ where $P_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n j^k$ for $2\le k \le 10$

Tags: numerical-methods, euler-maclaurin

I am not familiar with the Euler–Maclaurin formula. Any idea how to Use the Euler–Maclaurin formula to find $P_{k+1}$ where $P_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n j^k$ for $2\le k \le 10$? Thanks!

Comment: You are to apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula to $f(x)=x^k$.

Comment: What about using polynomial interpolation? What's the difference?